# Rounded corners for digital portfolio

Tags: transparency, file-format, portfolio

I'm creating my architecture portfolio, which will be printed but also distributed digitally. I'd like my pages to have rounded corners (to be similar to those of a writing journal, for example) - which is easily solved for the printed version, but I want the pages of the digital version to display on the screen with rounded corners. How can I achieve this? What is the best format (PDF, PNG, etc.) to display this and distribute via email?

Programmes I use: Adobe Illustrator, Photoshop and InDesign (all CS6).

Comment: All bitmap images on a screen are rectangular. Just draw the rounded corners on your images.

Answer (score 1):

PNGs make for poor portfolios because they would be very large image files and would be not very user friendly (cannot highlight, copy, resize, etc.).

You can avoid this by making your portfolio using web technology (HTML + CSS). This allows you to style it however you wish while still retaining usability.

The alternative is to simply not use rounded corners. Most portfolios are distributed using PDFs which do not allow for this very easily.